# libdeflate_zlib_decompress error when creating a .TIFF w/ Sentinel-hub API

Tags: python, zlib, tiff

I am working with the sentinel hub API In Python using sentinelhub-py on Windows.

I am following the examples as written in the documentation on [this page](https://sentinelhub-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/process_request.html#Example-1:-True-color-(PNG)-on-a-specific-date)

The following code extracts data through the API: First the evalscript selects the number of bands and the SentinelHubRequest returns the data as a .PNG file

```
evalscript_true_color = """
    //VERSION=3

    function setup() {
        return {
            input: [{
                bands: ["B02", "B03", "B04"]
            }],
            output: {
                bands: 3
            }
        };
    }

    function evaluatePixel(sample) {
        return [sample.B04, sample.B03, sample.B02];
    }
"""

request_true_color = SentinelHubRequest(
    evalscript=evalscript_true_color,
    input_data=[
        SentinelHubRequest.input_data(
            data_collection=DataCollection.SENTINEL2_L1C,
            time_interval=("2020-06-12", "2020-06-13"),
        )
    ],
    responses=[SentinelHubRequest.output_response("default", MimeType.PNG)],
    bbox=betsiboka_bbox,
    size=betsiboka_size,
    config=config,
)

true_color_imgs = request_true_color.get_data()
```

This request is working fine, however when I change MimeType to MimeType.TIFF this error keeps appearing:

***DeflateError**: libdeflate_zlib_decompress returned LIBDEFLATE_BAD_DATA*

When I use the code a bit below that downloads the data for all 13 bands, as shown here: [https://sentinelhub-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/process_request.html#Example-3:-All-Sentinel-2's-raw-band-values](https://sentinelhub-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/process_request.html#Example-3:-All-Sentinel-2%27s-raw-band-values)

```
evalscript_all_bands = """
    //VERSION=3
    function setup() {
        return {
            input: [{
                bands: ["B01","B02","B03","B04","B05","B06","B07","B08","B8A","B09","B10","B11","B12"],
                units: "DN"
            }],
            output: {
                bands: 13,
                sampleType: "INT16"
            }
        };
    }

    function evaluatePixel(sample) {
        return [sample.B01,
                sample.B02,
                sample.B03,
                sample.B04,
                sample.B05,
                sample.B06,
                sample.B07,
                sample.B08,
                sample.B8A,
                sample.B09,
                sample.B10,
                sample.B11,
                sample.B12];
    }
"""

request_all_bands = SentinelHubRequest(
    evalscript=evalscript_all_bands,
    input_data=[
        SentinelHubRequest.input_data(
            data_collection=DataCollection.SENTINEL2_L1C,
            time_interval=("2020-06-01", "2020-06-30"),
            mosaicking_order=MosaickingOrder.LEAST_CC,
        )
    ],
    responses=[SentinelHubRequest.output_response("default", MimeType.TIFF)],
    bbox=betsiboka_bbox,
    size=betsiboka_size,
    config=config,
)

all_bands_response = request_all_bands.get_data()
```

and then try to use their code to generate a .TIFF file I get this error:

***DeflateError:** libdeflate_zlib_decompress returned LIBDEFLATE_INSUFFICIENT_SPACE*

What I tried is producing a .TIFF file with only 3 bands and changing the sampleType to "INT8" or leaving it out, aswell as leaving out the unit="DN" (digital numbers) in the eval script,

and I tried increasing the buffersize to 10 GB with

```
import os

# Set the buffer size to 10000 MB (in bytes)
buffer_size = 1024 * 1024 * 10000

os.environ['ZLIB_BUF_SIZE'] = str(buffer_size)
```

and I installed gdal library, as a last resort, but the error persists and I can find no info on this error.

Does anyone have experience with this error (I'm using Windows) and can provide me a hint or a solution?

Comment: Thanks Mark, seems to be an issue with the new sentinelhub-py version 3.9.0, downgrading to 3.8.4 resolved the issue.